# What is the resulting vector's angle if two vectors point in the same direction?

Tags: geometry

Suppose we have three vectors of equal magnitude (like phasors along the unit circle). Now if two of them have angle $\theta_1$ and one has angle $\theta_2$, **can we say that the resultant vectors angle will be the following?** $$ \theta_{tot} = \frac{2\theta_{1} + \theta_{2}}{3} $$

I tried simulations in matlab and the angle comes out to be approximately what the above expression shows. But is this correct and how can be this proved?

Comment: What is "the resultant vector"? The sum of the three vectors? Their product as complex numbers?

Comment: the sum of three vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be extrapolating from the case of two unit vectors (which is also not 100% correct), but: **No**.
For example, with vectors $(1,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(0,1)$, the resultant (i.e., sum) vector is $(2,1)$, but $\frac 12\ne\tan30^°$.

In fact, if the answer were *Yes*, we could easily perform angle trisection with a straightedge and compass construction.

Comment: Even simpler example: $(1, 0), (1, 0)$ and $(-1, 0)$. And just for some completeness: the true relationship between the angles requires trigonometry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if the vectors are very close to one another? You considered a kind of extreme case but what if the two vectors have an angle of say 30 and the third one has an angle of 40?